# Android - How to increase EditText value?

Tags: android, android-activity

I'm new to android development..
I have this code in my main class:

```
Button prevBtn, pauseBtn, nextBtn;
EditText counterTxt;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_affirmations);         

      SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

        prevBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.prevBtn);
        pauseBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.pauseBtn);
        nextBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.nextBtn);        
        counterTxt = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.counterTxt);  

        prevBtn.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {        
            int t = Integer.parseInt(counterTxt.getText().toString());      

            public void onClick(View v) {
                counterTxt.setText(String.valueOf(t-1));                
            }       

        });


        nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {        
            int t = Integer.parseInt(counterTxt.getText().toString());

            public void onClick(View v) {
                counterTxt.setText(String.valueOf(t+1));                
            }       

        });     



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_affirmations, menu);
    return true;
}
```

When I click "Previous", the text field value becomes 19.

When I click "Next", the text field value becomes 21.

But it only displays these two values, nothing else, no matter if i click again. I want to subtract or add 1 whenever i click the appropriate buttons.

I think this happens because the event Listeners are inside onCreate() method? Any idea on how to make it update each time I click?

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to move your `parseInt` inside your `onClick`:

```
nextBtn.setOnClickListener(new  View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            int t = Integer.parseInt(counterTxt.getText().toString());
            counterTxt.setText(String.valueOf(t+1));                
        }       

    });
```

Comment: Thank you, I can't believe I didn't see this :) It's because Android development (and Java) still confuses me. Thanks so much @Ralgha :)

Answer (score 1):

In both cases, `t` is defined as a member variable of the listener, and never changed. move it inside the `onClick` method instead, like this (in both cases):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    int t = Integer.parseInt(counterTxt.getText().toString());
    counterTxt.setText(String.valueOf(t-1));                
}
```